# Why custom metabox value being added to the permalink

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this code to add a custom meta box `speaker` to the custom post type `event`.

```
/* 
|--------------------------------------------
| Speaker Meta Box in events
|--------------------------------------------
*/
function speaker_box() { 
    add_meta_box( 
        'speaker',
        __( 'Speaker', 'dbem' ),
        'speaker_box_content',
        'event',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'speaker_box' );

/* 
|--------------------------------------------
| Speaker meta box content in events
|--------------------------------------------
*/
function speaker_box_content( $post ) { 
    // generate a nonce field
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'dbem-speaker-nonce' );
    // get previously saved meta values (if any)
    $speaker = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'speaker', true );
    echo '<label for="speaker"></label>';
    echo '<select name="speaker" id="speaker">';
    echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
    foreach (get_speakers() as $key => $value) {
        if($speaker == $key) {
            echo '<option value="'.$key.'" selected="selected">'.$value.'</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}

/* 
|--------------------------------------------
| Get all speakers
|--------------------------------------------
*/
function get_speakers() { 

    $output = array();

    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'speaker',
    );
    $speakers = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $speakers->have_posts() ) {
      while( $speakers->have_posts() ) {
        $speakers->the_post();
        $output[get_the_ID()] = get_the_title();
      }
    }
    return $output; 
}
```

[image]

I have `post name` selected in permalink settings. But here instead of adding event title to the permalink, it's adding the last drop-down item text of the `speaker` metabox and some number to the url. What is wrong here? I have tested this by commenting the above code, the problem comes with this code only.

Save function,

```
function speaker_box_save( $post_id ) { 

  if ( 'event' != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    return;
  } 
  $speaker = $_POST['speaker'];
  if( isset($speaker)) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'speaker', $speaker );
  }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'speaker_box_save' );
```

Comment: the code above doesn't output any url/link so I can't relate your code to your question

could you also please indicate how did you get the permalinks of your events posts cheers

Comment: @Maai The problem is when I added this code to generate custom metabox to my CPT, it's affecting permalinks also.

Comment: the code above does 4 things
1. create a meta box
2. wp_query
3. add action
4. get post meta

so I can't think of a way that this code can affect/change your permalinks or your posts

have you tried removing this piece of code and see if the permalinks are going back to normal/as it should be?

Comment: Me too. I can't see any relation between the code and the problem described. Tried to add this code and ok, does what it looks it does and nothing else... (?)

Comment: @brasofilo Please check once again, I have updated question.

Comment: @Maai Please check once again, I have updated question.

Comment: Show the action for `save_post`, that's the only place where the problem could be (if it's related to the meta box)

Comment: @brasofilo Question updated with save action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how or why, but `WP_Query` is affecting the post slug of newly created posts. It takes the last `speaker` and uses it as slug of the new `event` being added.

One wonders why this is the most frequent Q&A at WordPress Developers:
[**When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Using the following stops the strange issue:

```
function get_speakers() { 
    $output = array();
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    );
    $speakers = get_posts( $args );
    if( $speakers ) {
        foreach( $speakers as $spk ) {
            $output[$spk->ID] = $spk->post_title;
        }
    }
    return $output; 
}
```